# jQuery UI Drag with Google Map

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps

I have problem with jQuery UI drag.

in div.popup has Google Map.
The problem is when move Google map, it also move div.popup.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.popup').draggable();
});
```

Comment: Is there any option that can disable block div to drag?

Comment: Try to create a div inside your "div.popup" and put into it your Google Map. Then drag it and check if it keeps working wrong. By the way, put here your `div.popup` code to see what you did.